# Server-Address in client-side java

Tags: java, webserver, ip-address, hostname

I'm trying to get the address that the client has accessed my server.

- If the client accesses the server with `http://localhost:8890` then
  the server should read exactly `http://localhost:8890`.
- If the client accesses the server with `http://127.0.0.1:8890` then
  the server should read exactly `http://127.0.0.1:8890`.
- If the client accesses the server with `http://mywebsite.com:8890`
  then the server should read exactly `http://mywebsite.com:8890`.

I got it partially with the function: `[SOCKET].getInetAddress().getHostName()`

But the client access `http://127.0.0.1:8890` function `[SOCKET].getInetAddress().getHostName()` return it `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`.

I need the server to get the address as the client that sent data as `COOKIES` not lost any chance redirection occurs (`302 Found` or `301 Moved Permanently`).

I searched everywhere, especially in the OS, but I do not know what search terms to use (if someone already asked this question), so excuse me if this is a duplicate.

My code:

```
package com.[PACKAGE];

/*web server*/
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Locale;

/*Err*/
//import java.io.IOException;

public class miniWebServer {
    private int port;
    private ServerSocket mySocket;
    private Socket remote;
    private Thread trd;

    public miniWebServer(int _port) {
        port = _port;
        initServer();
    }

    private void initServer(){
        trd = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                try {
                    //Criar socket
                    mySocket = new ServerSocket(port);
                    System.out.println("Conected!");
                    OK();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    String st = e.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.US);
                    if(st.indexOf("address already in use")!=-1){
                        System.out.println("Server ");
                        OK();
                    } else {
                        System.err.println("Erro ao tentar conectar com a port " + port + ": "+ e);
                    }
                    return;
                }
                listen();
            }
        });
        trd.start();
    }

    public void OK(){}//Override

    private void listen(){
        String addressClient = "";
        String portClient = "";
        PrintWriter outServer;

        for (;;) {
            try {
                //Esperando uma conexão (um cliente)
                remote = mySocket.accept();
                System.out.println("remote: "+remote.toString());
                System.out.println("getLocalAddress: "+remote.getLocalAddress().toString());
                System.out.println("getHostName: "+remote.getInetAddress().getHostName().toString());
                System.out.println("getLocalSocketAddress: "+remote.getLocalSocketAddress().toString());
                addressClient = remote.getInetAddress().getHostName().toString();
                portClient = Integer.toString(remote.getLocalPort());
                System.out.println("http://"+addressClient+":"+portClient);

                outServer = new PrintWriter(remote.getOutputStream());

                outServer.println("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
                outServer.println("Content-type: text/html");
                outServer.println("");
                outServer.println("<html>");
                outServer.println("<body>");
                outServer.println("<p>You address: http://"+addressClient+":"+portClient+"</p>");
                outServer.println("</body>");

                outServer.print("</html>");//last line

                outServer.flush();

                remote.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //System.out.println("loop::Error: " + e);
            }

            try {
                //Thread.currentThread();
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to use:

```
new miniWebServer(8890){
    @Override
    public void OK(){
        System.out.println("OK!");
    }
};
```

**Solution:**

Assuming I use the browser GoogleChrome, my java server will return this:

```
GET /folder/page.html HTTP/1.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:8890
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11
```

To get the headers and the request:
`inServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(remote.getInputStream()));`

then just extract the address of the `Host:` with `.slit(":")` or `new StringTokenizer(currentLine)`

Comment: Did you try to change `hosts` file to make `127.0.0.1 -> localhost` ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but It is not a matter of editing the `HOSTS` and yes programming. Please if you have any idea how to do this reply me, grateful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to use the complete GET request path as provided by HTTP. The lower level network won't distinguish between whether your client specified a host name or address (since the client itself will map a host name to an address - and what happens if your client is configured with a host / address mapping that your server doesn't have?)

Comment: In the `apache` server can address indentificar exactly what the customer requested. I need to work the same way (I need the server to get the address as the client that sent data as COOKIES not lost any chance redirection occurs (`302 Found` or `301 Moved Permanently`)). Thank you for your attention.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento - Apache has that information because it is included in the GET request to the server. This is what Brian Agnew is recommending you use. +1 btw.

Comment: Are you referring to `HEADERS` sent by the client? I will try.

Comment: Ok, it worked, I edited my question, I explained there how to use the "heades" to get hold of the address accessed by the client. Thankful. `+1 for @Bryan_Agnew` and `+1 for @Perception`, which led me to the solution.